# IBM JSONStore API return's "INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD' when used with OFFSET options

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We are using JSONStore API below in our Project and this was returning perfect values untill we have updated to the new IBM MFP plugin

> cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 8.0.2017082110

```
var options = {limit : 24 , offset : 24   };
WL.JSONStore.get(STORENAME).findAll(options).then(function(res){console.log(res)}).fail(function(err){console.log(err)});
```

The above code starts returning errors now after the update as follow

```
> ErrorObject {src: "find", err: 22, msg: "INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD", col:
> "STORENAME", usr: "jsonstore", …}col: "Assets"doc: {}err: 22msg:
> "INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD"res: {}src: "find"usr: "jsonstore"__proto__:
> Object
```

This after a long struggle found out its because of the "OFFSET" which we are using in options, if that gets removed it returns perfect values.

> This i have tested only in ANDROID Devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is appeared in android environment and will be fixed in the upcoming release of `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore` release.

For time being you can use the following fix which will resolve the issue :
https://ibm.box.com/s/ws4zwy0jqlh84ag1wf7yshrdsxgig4ll

Steps to apply test fix :

- Replace `ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundationjsonstore.jar` in your application project.
- Rebuild and run the application.